# editing Reg_multi_SZ it gives me this error "The type of the value object did not match the specified RegistryValueKind"

Tags: c#

When I use this code below:

```
RegistryKey RegSealWeb = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\SealWeb\Parameters\Java", true);


if (RegSealWeb != null)
{
    try
    {


        string[] RegSealWebString;
        RegSealWebString = (string[])RegSealWeb.GetValue("Options");
        StringBuilder RegSealWebStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string str in RegSealWebString)
        {

            if (str.Contains("config.url"))
            {
                RegSealWebStringBuilder.AppendLine("-Dseal.config.url=" + TXT_SCDIPaddress.Text + ":2181");


            }
            else
            {

                RegSealWebStringBuilder.AppendLine(str);

            }
        }

        RegSealWeb.SetValue("Options", RegSealWebStringBuilder, RegistryValueKind.MultiString);
        RegSealWeb.Close();
        Console.AppendText("Registry Java Key for Seal Web are Updated ");
        Console.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
```

It gives me the error "The type of the value object did not match the specified RegistryValueKind or the object could not be properly converted".

Does anybody know why? I tried to use a simple string that doesn't have any spaces and it gives me the same error. Writing to Reg_SZ or any other type is possible using this code but it cannot work with type reg_multi_sz.

appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an array of strings (like the one you get when you call GetValue) not a StringBuilder reference. Because your code doesn't know how many strings you end up adding then you can use a `List<string>` to add the elements and then convert it to an array when you write back the registry value.

```
string[] RegSealWebString;
RegSealWebString = (string[])RegSealWeb.GetValue("Options");
List<string> newValues = new List<string>();
foreach (string str in RegSealWebString)
{
    if (str.Contains("config.url"))
    {
        newValues.Add("-Dseal.config.url=" + TXT_SCDIPaddress.Text + ":2181");
    }
    else
    {
        newValues.Add(str);
    }
}
RegSealWeb.SetValue("Options", newValues.ToArray(), RegistryValueKind.MultiString);
```